# Tabulate With Category as Label

Tags: sas

I am trying to produce a table which contains totals for each group. 
I have sections, subsections and items. After each subsection 
a line with the totals of this subsection should appear and
after each section a line with the section total.

I tried using `proc tabulate` but the subtotals are just called Sum or another fixed label. I would like to use the category name for the subtotals.

## Example 1

First a small example to illustrate, below I have a complete running example
which shows what I tried with the proc tablulate and what I would like to achieve.

Input Data

```
==============================
Group   Group2  Item    Weight
-----   ------  ----    ------
Mammals Cats    Lion       215
Mammals Cats    Cheetah     70
Mammals Dogs    Wolf        80
Mammals Dogs    Jackal      45
==============================
```

Desired Result

```
===================
Group/Item   Weight
-----------  ------
    Lion        215
    Cheetah      70
  Cats          285
-----------  ------
    Wolf         80
    Jackal       45
  Dogs          125
-----------  ------
Mammals         410
===================
```

## Example 2

A slighly longer example in SAS code 
which also includes missing values

```
data animals;
input group1 $ group2 $ animal $ weight;
datalines;
Mammals Cats    Lion 215
Mammals Cats    Cheetah 70
Mammals Cats    Leopard 65
Mammals Dogs    Wolf 80
Mammals Dogs    Jackal 45
Birds   Raptors Eagle 6
Birds   Raptors Hawk 5
Birds   .       Duck 2
.       .       Snake 3
;
```

My unsuccessful attempt, the table is too complicated

```
PROC TABULATE DATA=ANIMALS OUT=ANIMAL_SUMMARY;
    VAR weight;

    CLASS group1 / ORDER=DATA MISSING;
    CLASS group2 / ORDER=DATA MISSING;
    CLASS animal / ORDER=DATA MISSING;

TABLE group1*(group2*(animal Sum) Sum) Sum, weight;
RUN;
```

A form of data close to the desired result

```
data target;
input group1 $ group2 $ animal $ weight;
datalines;
. . Lion 215
. . Cheetah 70
. . Leopard 65
. Cats . 350
. . Wolf 80
. . Jackal 45
. Dogs . 125
Mammals . . 475 
. . Eagle 6
. . Hawk 5
. Raptors . 11
. . Duck 2
Birds . . 13
. . Snake 3
. . . 491
;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can get *exactly* what you want from TABULATE. You'd probably have to go to Report to get exactly what you want.

You can get close, though.

```
PROC TABULATE DATA=ANIMALS OUT=ANIMAL_SUMMARY;
    VAR weight;

    CLASS group1 / ORDER=DATA MISSING;
    CLASS group2 / ORDER=DATA MISSING;
    CLASS animal / ORDER=DATA MISSING;

TABLE group1*(group2*(animal=' ' Sum=' '*group2=' ') Sum=' '*group1=' ') Sum='Total', weight;
RUN;
```

I'm adding `group2` and `group1` here, and removing a bunch of the labels.  It doesn't remove all of the labels for some reason, but it does remove most of them, and gets your group2/group1 on the right row.

It also gives a warning:

> Warning: A class variable is crossed with itself in the table statement at line 313.  This may cause unpredictable results.

That's fine, in this case, but just be aware of it (particularly if your shop is a 'clean log' shop; this may not work in that case).

Further than this I think you'd have to go to `PROC REPORT` to get, which is quite possible to do (REPORT is happy to do subtotal rows with `RBREAK` for example).

Comment: Particular thanks for the suggestion to use `PROC REPORT` i will need to do more reading about it, but it seems it is more suited to the task.